# How to fit a long table in several pages

Tags: tables

I'm trying to add some long tables to the appendix. However, Latex does not distribute it automatically on the needed pages. I also for the second table the headers are not compiling correctly. Maybe someone could help me with distributing evenly the table and help fix the headers?
[image]

Here the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,amsmath}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\hsize}}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash[b]{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} P @{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}
\section{xx}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} YYYcccY @{}}
    \toprule
    \bfseries \mytab{yy group} & 
    \bfseries \mytab{yy group long} &
    \bfseries \mytab{yy no~sens.} & 
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries yy} & 
    \bfseries \mytab{yy with sens.} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
    & & & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2}  \\
    \midrule
    1 &  R1HH1IC1 &   1.94 & 1.64 & 0.27 & 0.03 & 0.59 \\
    2 &  R1HH1IC2 &   2.94 & 1.56 & 1.03 & 0.34 & 3.10 \\
    3 &  R1HH1IC3 &   0.59 & 0.06 & 0.17 & 0.37 & 1.64 \\
    4 &  R1HH2IC1 &   2.86 & 2.41 & 0.40 & 0.04 & 0.88 \\
    5 &  R1HH2IC2 &   4.33 & 2.31 & 1.52 & 0.50 & 4.57 \\
    6 &  R1HH2IC3 &   0.87 & 0.08 & 0.25 & 0.54 & 2.42 \\
    7 &  R1HH3IC1 &   7.79 & 6.58 & 1.09 & 0.11 & 2.39 \\
    8 &  R1HH3IC2 &  11.80 & 6.29 & 4.15 & 1.36 &12.47 \\
    9 &  R1HH3IC3 &   2.38 & 0.23 & 0.67 & 1.48 & 6.59 \\
    10 &  R2HH1IC1 &   1.07 & 0.91 & 0.15 & 0.01 & 0.30 \\
    11 &  R2HH1IC2 &   2.86 & 1.60 & 1.11 & 0.15 & 2.56 \\
    12 &  R2HH1IC3 &   0.96 & 0.20 & 0.48 & 0.29 & 1.91 \\
    13 &  R2HH2IC1 &   1.55 & 1.32 & 0.22 & 0.01 & 0.44 \\
    14 &  R2HH2IC2 &   4.13 & 2.31 & 1.60 & 0.22 & 3.70 \\
    15 &  R2HH2IC3 &   1.39 & 0.29 & 0.69 & 0.42 & 2.76 \\
    16 &  R1HH3IC1 &   3.70 & 3.15 & 0.52 & 0.03 & 1.04 \\
    17 &  R2HH3IC2 &   9.85 & 5.51 & 3.82 & 0.52 & 8.82 \\
    18 &  R2HH3IC3 &   3.31 & 0.68 & 1.64 & 0.99 & 6.57 \\
    19 &  R3HH1IC1 &   0.31 & 0.23 & 0.07 & 0.00 & 0.14 \\
    20 &  R3HH1IC2 &   0.30 & 0.15 & 0.12 & 0.02 & 0.30 \\
    21 &  R3HH1IC3 &   0.21 & 0.04 & 0.11 & 0.05 & 0.40 \\
    22 &  R3HH2IC1 &   0.55 & 0.42 & 0.13 & 0.01 & 0.26 \\
    23 &  R3HH2IC2 &   0.54 & 0.27 & 0.23 & 0.04 & 0.54 \\
    24 &  R3HH2IC3 &   0.38 & 0.08 & 0.20 & 0.10 & 0.72 \\
    25 &  R3HH3IC1 &   2.56 & 1.92 & 0.61 & 0.03 & 1.21 \\
    26 &  R3HH3IC2 &   2.47 & 1.26 & 1.04 & 0.17 & 2.50 \\
    27 &  R3HH3IC3 &   1.75 & 0.35 & 0.94 & 0.45 & 3.35 \\
    28 &  R4HH1IC1 &   0.23 & 0.18 & 0.04 & 0.01 & 0.10 \\
    29 &  R4HH1IC2 &   0.94 & 0.50 & 0.40 & 0.04 & 0.88 \\
    30 &  R4HH1IC3 &   0.21 & 0.03 & 0.12 & 0.05 & 0.42 \\
    31 &  R4HH2IC1 &   0.39 & 0.31 & 0.07 & 0.01 & 0.17 \\
    32 &  R4HH2IC2 &   1.62 & 0.86 & 0.69 & 0.07 & 1.51 \\
    33 &  R4HH2IC3 &   0.36 & 0.05 & 0.21 & 0.09 & 0.72 \\
    34 &  R4HH3IC1 &   1.69 & 1.33 & 0.32 & 0.04 & 0.72 \\
    35 &  R4HH3IC2 &   7.00 & 3.70 & 3.00 & 0.30 & 6.52 \\
    36 &  R4HH3IC3 &   1.55 & 0.23 & 0.92 & 0.39 & 3.10 \\
    37 &  R5HH1IC1 &   0.29 & 0.22 & 0.06 & 0.01 & 0.14 \\
    38 &  R5HH1IC2 &   0.42 & 0.19 & 0.21 & 0.03 & 0.49 \\
    39 &  R5HH1IC3 &   0.14 & 0.02 & 0.07 & 0.05 & 0.29 \\
    40 &  R5HH2IC1 &   0.45 & 0.34 & 0.10 & 0.01 & 0.22 \\
    41 &  R5HH2IC2 &   0.66 & 0.29 & 0.32 & 0.05 & 0.76 \\
    42 &  R5HH2IC3 &   0.21 & 0.04 & 0.11 & 0.07 & 0.45 \\
    43 &  R5HH3IC1 &   1.94 & 1.47 & 0.42 & 0.05 & 0.96 \\
    44 &  R5HH3IC2 &   2.82 & 1.24 & 1.37 & 0.22 & 3.26 \\
    45 &  R5HH3IC3 &   0.91 & 0.16 & 0.45 & 0.30 & 1.92 \\
    46 &  R6HH1IC1 &   0.05 & 0.04 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.02 \\
    47 &  R6HH1IC2 &   0.14 & 0.06 & 0.06 & 0.01 & 0.15 \\
    48 &  R6HH1IC3 &   0.04 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.07 \\
    49 &  R6HH2IC1 &   0.08 & 0.06 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 0.03 \\
    50 &  R6HH2IC2 &   0.21 & 0.10 & 0.09 & 0.02 & 0.23 \\
    51 &  R6HH2IC3 &   0.06 & 0.01 & 0.03 & 0.02 & 0.11 \\
    52 &  R6HH3IC1 &   0.22 & 0.18 & 0.04 & 0.00 & 0.09 \\
    53 &  R6HH3IC2 &   0.58 & 0.27 & 0.26 & 0.05 & 0.64 \\
    54 &  R6HH3IC3 &   0.15 & 0.03 & 0.08 & 0.04 & 0.30 \\
    55 &  R7HH1IC1 &   0.11 & 0.09 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 0.04 \\
    56 &  R7HH1IC2 &   0.29 & 0.14 & 0.13 & 0.02 & 0.33 \\
    57 &  R7HH1IC3 &   0.08 & 0.02 & 0.04 & 0.02 & 0.15 \\
    58 &  R7HH2IC1 &   0.17 & 0.14 & 0.03 & 0.00 & 0.07 \\
    59 &  R7HH2IC2 &   0.45 & 0.21 & 0.20 & 0.04 & 0.50 \\
    60 &  R7HH2IC3 &   0.12 & 0.03 & 0.06 & 0.03 & 0.24 \\
    61 &  R7HH3IC1 &   0.48 & 0.38 & 0.09 & 0.01 & 0.19 \\
    62 &  R7HH3IC2 &   1.24 & 0.58 & 0.56 & 0.10 & 1.39 \\
    63 &  R7HH3IC3 &   0.33 & 0.07 & 0.17 & 0.09 & 0.65 \\
 \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:nn}
\end{table}

\section{yy}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} YYYcccY @{}}
    \toprule
    \bfseries \mytab{yy group} & 
    \bfseries \mytab{yy group long} &
    \bfseries \mytab{yy without~sens.} & 
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries yy} & 
    \bfseries \mytab{yy with sens.} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
    & & & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2}  \\
    \midrule
        1 & R1HH1IC1 &  193.81 & 163.81 &  27.21 &   2.78 & 59.48 \\
        2 & R1HH1IC2 &  293.53 & 156.41 & 103.29 &  33.83 &310.24 \\
        3 & R1HH1IC3 &   59.23 &   5.76 &  16.64 &  36.84 &163.90 \\
        4 & R1HH2IC1 &  285.68 & 241.47 &  40.10 &   4.10 & 87.68 \\
        5 & R1HH2IC2 &  432.68 & 230.56 & 152.25 &  49.87 &457.30 \\
        6 & R1HH2IC3 &   87.31 &   8.49 &  24.53 &  54.30 &241.59 \\
        7 & R1HH3IC1 &  779.00 & 658.45 & 109.36 &  11.19 &239.08 \\
        8 & R1HH3IC2 & 1179.85 & 628.70 & 415.16 & 135.99 & 1246.99 \\
        9 & R1HH3IC3 &  238.09 &  23.14 &  66.88 & 148.07 &658.79 \\
        10 & R2HH1IC1 &  107.41 &  91.50 &  15.11 &   0.81 & 30.35 \\
        11 & R2HH1IC2 &  286.10 & 160.04 & 110.88 &  15.18 &256.33 \\
        12 & R2HH1IC3 &   96.26 &  19.85 &  47.61 &  28.81 &190.95 \\
        13 & R2HH2IC1 &  155.08 & 132.10 &  21.82 &   1.16 & 43.82 \\
        14 & R2HH2IC2 &  413.07 & 231.06 & 160.09 &  21.92 &370.08 \\
        15 & R2HH2IC3 &  138.98 &  28.66 &  68.74 &  41.59 &275.70 \\
        16 & R1HH3IC1 &  369.72 & 314.93 &  52.01 &   2.78 &104.47 \\
        17 & R2HH3IC2 &  984.77 & 550.86 & 381.66 &  52.25 &882.28 \\
        18 & R2HH3IC3 &  331.34 &  68.32 & 163.87 &  99.16 &657.27 \\
        19 & R3HH1IC1 &   30.59 &  22.96 &   7.31 &   0.32 & 14.43 \\
        20 & R3HH1IC2 &   29.59 &  15.12 &  12.48 &   1.99 & 29.88 \\
        21 & R3HH1IC3 &   20.90 &   4.24 &  11.23 &   5.43 & 40.08 \\
        22 & R3HH2IC1 &   55.32 &  41.52 &  13.21 &   0.58 & 26.09 \\
        23 & R3HH2IC2 &   53.50 &  27.33 &  22.57 &   3.60 & 54.02 \\
        24 & R3HH2IC3 &   37.78 &   7.67 &  20.30 &   9.82 & 72.47 \\
        25 & R3HH3IC1 &  255.54 & 191.81 &  61.04 &   2.69 &120.54 \\
        26 & R3HH3IC2 &  247.17 & 126.27 & 104.28 &  16.61 &249.55 \\
        27 & R3HH3IC3 &  174.54 &  35.42 &  93.77 &  45.36 &334.80 \\
        28 & R4HH1IC1 &   22.69 &  17.88 &   4.30 &   0.51 &  9.66 \\
        29 & R4HH1IC2 &   94.06 &  49.78 &  40.29 &   4.00 & 87.62 \\
        30 & R4HH1IC3 &   20.77 &   3.14 &  12.33 &   5.30 & 41.62 \\
        31 & R4HH2IC1 &   39.05 &  30.77 &   7.40 &   0.88 & 16.62 \\
        32 & R4HH2IC2 &  161.83 &  85.64 &  69.32 &   6.88 &150.76 \\
        33 & R4HH2IC3 &   35.74 &   5.40 &  21.21 &   9.12 & 71.61 \\
        34 & R4HH3IC1 &  168.89 & 133.08 &  32.01 &   3.80 & 71.90 \\
        35 & R4HH3IC2 &  700.01 & 370.43 & 299.83 &  29.74 &652.09 \\
        36 & R4HH3IC3 &  154.59 &  23.37 &  91.75 &  39.47 &309.75 \\
        37 & R5HH1IC1 &   29.29 &  22.16 &   6.34 &   0.79 & 14.39 \\
        38 & R5HH1IC2 &   42.45 &  18.63 &  20.57 &   3.25 & 49.13 \\
        39 & R5HH1IC3 &   13.72 &   2.34 &   6.81 &   4.57 & 28.95 \\
        40 & R5HH2IC1 &   45.21 &  34.20 &   9.79 &   1.22 & 22.21 \\
        41 & R5HH2IC2 &   65.52 &  28.75 &  31.75 &   5.02 & 75.84 \\
        42 & R5HH2IC3 &   21.18 &   3.62 &  10.51 &   7.06 & 44.68 \\
        43 & R5HH3IC1 &  194.46 & 147.10 &  42.09 &   5.27 & 95.51 \\
        44 & R5HH3IC2 &  281.80 & 123.65 & 136.55 &  21.60 &326.19 \\
        45 & R5HH3IC3 &   91.10 &  15.55 &  45.20 &  30.35 &192.18 \\
        46 & R6HH1IC1 &    5.22 &   4.15 &   1.00 &   0.07 &  2.05 \\
        47 & R6HH1IC2 &   13.50 &   6.32 &   6.04 &   1.14 & 15.10 \\
        48 & R6HH1IC3 &    3.61 &   0.75 &   1.84 &   1.03 &  7.06 \\
        49 & R6HH2IC1 &    8.05 &   6.41 &   1.54 &   0.10 &  3.17 \\
        50 & R6HH2IC2 &   20.85 &   9.77 &   9.33 &   1.76 & 23.31 \\
        51 & R6HH2IC3 &    5.58 &   1.16 &   2.84 &   1.59 & 10.90 \\
        52 & R6HH3IC1 &   22.21 &  17.68 &   4.25 &   0.28 &  8.74 \\
        53 & R6HH3IC2 &   57.50 &  26.93 &  25.72 &   4.85 & 64.29 \\
        54 & R6HH3IC3 &   15.38 &   3.19 &   7.82 &   4.37 & 30.06 \\
        55 & R7HH1IC1 &   11.29 &   8.99 &   2.16 &   0.14 &  4.44 \\
        56 & R7HH1IC2 &   29.23 &  13.69 &  13.08 &   2.47 & 32.68 \\
        57 & R7HH1IC3 &    7.82 &   1.62 &   3.98 &   2.22 & 15.28 \\
        58 & R7HH2IC1 &   17.44 &  13.88 &   3.34 &   0.22 &  6.86 \\
        59 & R7HH2IC2 &   45.14 &  21.14 &  20.19 &   3.81 & 50.46 \\
        60 & R7HH2IC3 &   12.08 &   2.50 &   6.14 &   3.43 & 23.60 \\
        61 & R7HH3IC1 &   48.09 &  38.27 &   9.20 &   0.61 & 18.92 \\
        62 & R7HH3IC2 &  124.48 &  58.30 &  55.69 &  10.50 &139.17 \\
        63 & R7HH3IC3 &   33.30 &   6.90 &  16.93 &   9.46 & 65.08 \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:nn}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Long table had not to be inside `table` float. Remove `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one of the long tables, e.g. `longtable` or `xltabular`; particularly, the latter, which accepts `X`-type columns.

The code below has slightly altered captions on subsequent pages to indicate continuing parts. The header itself seems the same for each table and is defined in a simple macro to avoid repetition.

Here's the code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\hsize}}

\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash{\bfseries
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}P@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}

\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}

\newcommand\headdef{% Added to avoid repeating parts
    \toprule
    \mytab{yy\\group} & 
    \mytab{yy\\group long} &
    \mytab{yy\\no~sens.} & 
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{yy}} & 
    \mytab{yy with sens.} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
    & & & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2}  \\
    \midrule}


\begin{document}
\section{xx}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} YYYcccY @{}}
    %%% The first header
    \caption{Caption 1}\label{tab:nn1} \\
    \headdef\endfirsthead
    %%% The header on subsequent pages
    \caption{Caption 1 \textit{(Continued)}} \\[-2ex]
    \headdef\endhead
    %%% The footer
    \bottomrule\endfoot
    1 &  R1HH1IC1 &   1.94 & 1.64 & 0.27 & 0.03 & 0.59 \\
    2 &  R1HH1IC2 &   2.94 & 1.56 & 1.03 & 0.34 & 3.10 \\
    3 &  R1HH1IC3 &   0.59 & 0.06 & 0.17 & 0.37 & 1.64 \\
    4 &  R1HH2IC1 &   2.86 & 2.41 & 0.40 & 0.04 & 0.88 \\
    5 &  R1HH2IC2 &   4.33 & 2.31 & 1.52 & 0.50 & 4.57 \\
    6 &  R1HH2IC3 &   0.87 & 0.08 & 0.25 & 0.54 & 2.42 \\
    7 &  R1HH3IC1 &   7.79 & 6.58 & 1.09 & 0.11 & 2.39 \\
    8 &  R1HH3IC2 &  11.80 & 6.29 & 4.15 & 1.36 &12.47 \\
    9 &  R1HH3IC3 &   2.38 & 0.23 & 0.67 & 1.48 & 6.59 \\
    10 &  R2HH1IC1 &   1.07 & 0.91 & 0.15 & 0.01 & 0.30 \\
    11 &  R2HH1IC2 &   2.86 & 1.60 & 1.11 & 0.15 & 2.56 \\
    12 &  R2HH1IC3 &   0.96 & 0.20 & 0.48 & 0.29 & 1.91 \\
    13 &  R2HH2IC1 &   1.55 & 1.32 & 0.22 & 0.01 & 0.44 \\
    14 &  R2HH2IC2 &   4.13 & 2.31 & 1.60 & 0.22 & 3.70 \\
    15 &  R2HH2IC3 &   1.39 & 0.29 & 0.69 & 0.42 & 2.76 \\
    16 &  R1HH3IC1 &   3.70 & 3.15 & 0.52 & 0.03 & 1.04 \\
    17 &  R2HH3IC2 &   9.85 & 5.51 & 3.82 & 0.52 & 8.82 \\
    18 &  R2HH3IC3 &   3.31 & 0.68 & 1.64 & 0.99 & 6.57 \\
    19 &  R3HH1IC1 &   0.31 & 0.23 & 0.07 & 0.00 & 0.14 \\
    20 &  R3HH1IC2 &   0.30 & 0.15 & 0.12 & 0.02 & 0.30 \\
    21 &  R3HH1IC3 &   0.21 & 0.04 & 0.11 & 0.05 & 0.40 \\
    22 &  R3HH2IC1 &   0.55 & 0.42 & 0.13 & 0.01 & 0.26 \\
    23 &  R3HH2IC2 &   0.54 & 0.27 & 0.23 & 0.04 & 0.54 \\
    24 &  R3HH2IC3 &   0.38 & 0.08 & 0.20 & 0.10 & 0.72 \\
    25 &  R3HH3IC1 &   2.56 & 1.92 & 0.61 & 0.03 & 1.21 \\
    26 &  R3HH3IC2 &   2.47 & 1.26 & 1.04 & 0.17 & 2.50 \\
    27 &  R3HH3IC3 &   1.75 & 0.35 & 0.94 & 0.45 & 3.35 \\
    28 &  R4HH1IC1 &   0.23 & 0.18 & 0.04 & 0.01 & 0.10 \\
    29 &  R4HH1IC2 &   0.94 & 0.50 & 0.40 & 0.04 & 0.88 \\
    30 &  R4HH1IC3 &   0.21 & 0.03 & 0.12 & 0.05 & 0.42 \\
    31 &  R4HH2IC1 &   0.39 & 0.31 & 0.07 & 0.01 & 0.17 \\
    32 &  R4HH2IC2 &   1.62 & 0.86 & 0.69 & 0.07 & 1.51 \\
    33 &  R4HH2IC3 &   0.36 & 0.05 & 0.21 & 0.09 & 0.72 \\
    34 &  R4HH3IC1 &   1.69 & 1.33 & 0.32 & 0.04 & 0.72 \\
    35 &  R4HH3IC2 &   7.00 & 3.70 & 3.00 & 0.30 & 6.52 \\
    36 &  R4HH3IC3 &   1.55 & 0.23 & 0.92 & 0.39 & 3.10 \\
    37 &  R5HH1IC1 &   0.29 & 0.22 & 0.06 & 0.01 & 0.14 \\
    38 &  R5HH1IC2 &   0.42 & 0.19 & 0.21 & 0.03 & 0.49 \\
    39 &  R5HH1IC3 &   0.14 & 0.02 & 0.07 & 0.05 & 0.29 \\
    40 &  R5HH2IC1 &   0.45 & 0.34 & 0.10 & 0.01 & 0.22 \\
    41 &  R5HH2IC2 &   0.66 & 0.29 & 0.32 & 0.05 & 0.76 \\
    42 &  R5HH2IC3 &   0.21 & 0.04 & 0.11 & 0.07 & 0.45 \\
    43 &  R5HH3IC1 &   1.94 & 1.47 & 0.42 & 0.05 & 0.96 \\
    44 &  R5HH3IC2 &   2.82 & 1.24 & 1.37 & 0.22 & 3.26 \\
    45 &  R5HH3IC3 &   0.91 & 0.16 & 0.45 & 0.30 & 1.92 \\
    46 &  R6HH1IC1 &   0.05 & 0.04 & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.02 \\
    47 &  R6HH1IC2 &   0.14 & 0.06 & 0.06 & 0.01 & 0.15 \\
    48 &  R6HH1IC3 &   0.04 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.07 \\
    49 &  R6HH2IC1 &   0.08 & 0.06 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 0.03 \\
    50 &  R6HH2IC2 &   0.21 & 0.10 & 0.09 & 0.02 & 0.23 \\
    51 &  R6HH2IC3 &   0.06 & 0.01 & 0.03 & 0.02 & 0.11 \\
    52 &  R6HH3IC1 &   0.22 & 0.18 & 0.04 & 0.00 & 0.09 \\
    53 &  R6HH3IC2 &   0.58 & 0.27 & 0.26 & 0.05 & 0.64 \\
    54 &  R6HH3IC3 &   0.15 & 0.03 & 0.08 & 0.04 & 0.30 \\
    55 &  R7HH1IC1 &   0.11 & 0.09 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 0.04 \\
    56 &  R7HH1IC2 &   0.29 & 0.14 & 0.13 & 0.02 & 0.33 \\
    57 &  R7HH1IC3 &   0.08 & 0.02 & 0.04 & 0.02 & 0.15 \\
    58 &  R7HH2IC1 &   0.17 & 0.14 & 0.03 & 0.00 & 0.07 \\
    59 &  R7HH2IC2 &   0.45 & 0.21 & 0.20 & 0.04 & 0.50 \\
    60 &  R7HH2IC3 &   0.12 & 0.03 & 0.06 & 0.03 & 0.24 \\
    61 &  R7HH3IC1 &   0.48 & 0.38 & 0.09 & 0.01 & 0.19 \\
    62 &  R7HH3IC2 &   1.24 & 0.58 & 0.56 & 0.10 & 1.39 \\
    63 &  R7HH3IC3 &   0.33 & 0.07 & 0.17 & 0.09 & 0.65 \\
\end{xltabular}

\section{yy}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} YYYcccY @{}}
    %%% The first header
    \caption{Caption 2}\label{tab:nn2} \\
    \headdef\endfirsthead
    %%% The header on subsequent pages
    \caption{Caption 2 \textit{(Continued)}} \\[-2ex]
    \headdef\endhead
    %%% The footer
    \bottomrule\endfoot
    1 & R1HH1IC1 &  193.81 & 163.81 &  27.21 &   2.78 & 59.48 \\
    2 & R1HH1IC2 &  293.53 & 156.41 & 103.29 &  33.83 &310.24 \\
    3 & R1HH1IC3 &   59.23 &   5.76 &  16.64 &  36.84 &163.90 \\
    4 & R1HH2IC1 &  285.68 & 241.47 &  40.10 &   4.10 & 87.68 \\
    5 & R1HH2IC2 &  432.68 & 230.56 & 152.25 &  49.87 &457.30 \\
    6 & R1HH2IC3 &   87.31 &   8.49 &  24.53 &  54.30 &241.59 \\
    7 & R1HH3IC1 &  779.00 & 658.45 & 109.36 &  11.19 &239.08 \\
    8 & R1HH3IC2 & 1179.85 & 628.70 & 415.16 & 135.99 & 1246.99 \\
    9 & R1HH3IC3 &  238.09 &  23.14 &  66.88 & 148.07 &658.79 \\
    10 & R2HH1IC1 &  107.41 &  91.50 &  15.11 &   0.81 & 30.35 \\
    11 & R2HH1IC2 &  286.10 & 160.04 & 110.88 &  15.18 &256.33 \\
    12 & R2HH1IC3 &   96.26 &  19.85 &  47.61 &  28.81 &190.95 \\
    13 & R2HH2IC1 &  155.08 & 132.10 &  21.82 &   1.16 & 43.82 \\
    14 & R2HH2IC2 &  413.07 & 231.06 & 160.09 &  21.92 &370.08 \\
    15 & R2HH2IC3 &  138.98 &  28.66 &  68.74 &  41.59 &275.70 \\
    16 & R1HH3IC1 &  369.72 & 314.93 &  52.01 &   2.78 &104.47 \\
    17 & R2HH3IC2 &  984.77 & 550.86 & 381.66 &  52.25 &882.28 \\
    18 & R2HH3IC3 &  331.34 &  68.32 & 163.87 &  99.16 &657.27 \\
    19 & R3HH1IC1 &   30.59 &  22.96 &   7.31 &   0.32 & 14.43 \\
    20 & R3HH1IC2 &   29.59 &  15.12 &  12.48 &   1.99 & 29.88 \\
    21 & R3HH1IC3 &   20.90 &   4.24 &  11.23 &   5.43 & 40.08 \\
    22 & R3HH2IC1 &   55.32 &  41.52 &  13.21 &   0.58 & 26.09 \\
    23 & R3HH2IC2 &   53.50 &  27.33 &  22.57 &   3.60 & 54.02 \\
    24 & R3HH2IC3 &   37.78 &   7.67 &  20.30 &   9.82 & 72.47 \\
    25 & R3HH3IC1 &  255.54 & 191.81 &  61.04 &   2.69 &120.54 \\
    26 & R3HH3IC2 &  247.17 & 126.27 & 104.28 &  16.61 &249.55 \\
    27 & R3HH3IC3 &  174.54 &  35.42 &  93.77 &  45.36 &334.80 \\
    28 & R4HH1IC1 &   22.69 &  17.88 &   4.30 &   0.51 &  9.66 \\
    29 & R4HH1IC2 &   94.06 &  49.78 &  40.29 &   4.00 & 87.62 \\
    30 & R4HH1IC3 &   20.77 &   3.14 &  12.33 &   5.30 & 41.62 \\
    31 & R4HH2IC1 &   39.05 &  30.77 &   7.40 &   0.88 & 16.62 \\
    32 & R4HH2IC2 &  161.83 &  85.64 &  69.32 &   6.88 &150.76 \\
    33 & R4HH2IC3 &   35.74 &   5.40 &  21.21 &   9.12 & 71.61 \\
    34 & R4HH3IC1 &  168.89 & 133.08 &  32.01 &   3.80 & 71.90 \\
    35 & R4HH3IC2 &  700.01 & 370.43 & 299.83 &  29.74 &652.09 \\
    36 & R4HH3IC3 &  154.59 &  23.37 &  91.75 &  39.47 &309.75 \\
    37 & R5HH1IC1 &   29.29 &  22.16 &   6.34 &   0.79 & 14.39 \\
    38 & R5HH1IC2 &   42.45 &  18.63 &  20.57 &   3.25 & 49.13 \\
    39 & R5HH1IC3 &   13.72 &   2.34 &   6.81 &   4.57 & 28.95 \\
    40 & R5HH2IC1 &   45.21 &  34.20 &   9.79 &   1.22 & 22.21 \\
    41 & R5HH2IC2 &   65.52 &  28.75 &  31.75 &   5.02 & 75.84 \\
    42 & R5HH2IC3 &   21.18 &   3.62 &  10.51 &   7.06 & 44.68 \\
    43 & R5HH3IC1 &  194.46 & 147.10 &  42.09 &   5.27 & 95.51 \\
    44 & R5HH3IC2 &  281.80 & 123.65 & 136.55 &  21.60 &326.19 \\
    45 & R5HH3IC3 &   91.10 &  15.55 &  45.20 &  30.35 &192.18 \\
    46 & R6HH1IC1 &    5.22 &   4.15 &   1.00 &   0.07 &  2.05 \\
    47 & R6HH1IC2 &   13.50 &   6.32 &   6.04 &   1.14 & 15.10 \\
    48 & R6HH1IC3 &    3.61 &   0.75 &   1.84 &   1.03 &  7.06 \\
    49 & R6HH2IC1 &    8.05 &   6.41 &   1.54 &   0.10 &  3.17 \\
    50 & R6HH2IC2 &   20.85 &   9.77 &   9.33 &   1.76 & 23.31 \\
    51 & R6HH2IC3 &    5.58 &   1.16 &   2.84 &   1.59 & 10.90 \\
    52 & R6HH3IC1 &   22.21 &  17.68 &   4.25 &   0.28 &  8.74 \\
    53 & R6HH3IC2 &   57.50 &  26.93 &  25.72 &   4.85 & 64.29 \\
    54 & R6HH3IC3 &   15.38 &   3.19 &   7.82 &   4.37 & 30.06 \\
    55 & R7HH1IC1 &   11.29 &   8.99 &   2.16 &   0.14 &  4.44 \\
    56 & R7HH1IC2 &   29.23 &  13.69 &  13.08 &   2.47 & 32.68 \\
    57 & R7HH1IC3 &    7.82 &   1.62 &   3.98 &   2.22 & 15.28 \\
    58 & R7HH2IC1 &   17.44 &  13.88 &   3.34 &   0.22 &  6.86 \\
    59 & R7HH2IC2 &   45.14 &  21.14 &  20.19 &   3.81 & 50.46 \\
    60 & R7HH2IC3 &   12.08 &   2.50 &   6.14 &   3.43 & 23.60 \\
    61 & R7HH3IC1 &   48.09 &  38.27 &   9.20 &   0.61 & 18.92 \\
    62 & R7HH3IC2 &  124.48 &  58.30 &  55.69 &  10.50 &139.17 \\
    63 & R7HH3IC3 &   33.30 &   6.90 &  16.93 &   9.46 & 65.08 \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It works nicely!